# SQLCODE -1390 connecting to DB2 64 bit client from 32 bit app

Tags: windows-7, db2, database-connection, windows-7-x64

I've got a 32 bit application that connects normally to a DB2 database. (written in C)
When I run it on a machine with a DB2 64 bit client, I get a SQLCODE -1390 from connect.
(Win7 64 Bit, DB2 V9.7 client 64 bit)

Connecting from the command line works (db2 connect to ...)
With a 32 Bit DB2 client on the same Win7 64 Bit machine, the connect also works.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it ?
Best regards
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

IBM DB2 Fixpack 1 solved the problem !